# How can I obtain the time at which the first byte of a web page loads in Safari?

Tags: javascript

In Google Chrome, I can use `window.performance.timing.responseStart` to obtain the time at which the first byte of a web page loads in javascript.

Safari lacks the `performance` object. How can I get the same time in Safari?

Comment: Looks like Safari 8 supports it... http://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing not sure if upgrading is an option, but thought I'd share this.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533456/time-to-first-byte-with-javascript

Comment: Oh thanks, is there a way I can find out which browsers/versions support window.performance? Or the relevant W3C interface in general?

Comment: Ah, I can defer to caniuse: http://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing