# Event handler for time to first byte in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, time-to-first-byte

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533456/time-to-first-byte-with-javascript) is similar but did not help.

Users upload files to our server for processing then download the result. This all happens within a single AJAX call on a web page.

Because the downloaded files are large, we would like to indicate when downloading has begun.

Is there an event that gets triggered when the first byte has been received?

We use jQuery so jQuery answers are ideal, but anything that works in pure JavaScript also works.